# How to properly evaluate a Green's equation in FeynCalc (or any other package)?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, feyncalc

In 4D, the Green's function of the box operator with respect to $p$ is $1/p^2$,i.e.

$$\partial_p^2 \frac{1}{p^2} = -(2\pi)^2 \delta^{(4)}(p). \tag{1}$$

I use the package FeynCalc, in which the computation of $(1)$ just returns $0$ by giving:

```
FourDivergence[FourDivergence[1/SP[p2,p2], FV[p, µ]], FV[p, µ]]
```

(SP is ScalarProduct, FV is FourVector) This is logical, since the computer first determines the first FourDivergence, then the second one, and this indeed seems to give $0$. But kind of annoying, since it is actually $\infty$ at $p=0$. As far as I know, there is no box operator implemented in FeynCalc.

I have to do a lot of complicated computations of the following type:

$$(\partial_{p_1}-\partial_{p_2})^2(\partial_{p_3}-\partial_{p_4})^2 \frac{f(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)}{p_1^2p_2^2p_3^2p_4^2}, \tag{2}$$

in which many terms are inadequately put to $0$ by Mathematica/FeynCalc for the reason mentioned above. Is there any way to implement eq.$(1)$ and still obtain reasonable results? Or is there another package that can perform the same operations while taking the missing terms into consideration?

Comment: Actually, I just found the operator "FourLaplacian" in FeynCalc!...but it also evaluates its Green's function to $0$.

Comment: As a workaround you can introduce a regulator `ep` as in `Together[FourDivergence[
  FourDivergence[1/(SP[p, p] + ep), FV[p, mu]], FV[p, mu]]]` to reveal terms that blow up for `p=0` and `ep->0`. Then use extra code to convert those to proper Dirac deltas. By default `FourDivergence` assumes that there are no singular terms, since it is designed for differentiating amplitudes, not solving differential equations.